# Symfony, dynamic form modification won't use Anonymous functions

Tags: php, forms, symfony, anonymous-function, symfony-2.3

Ok, here's the problem, I am using Symfony 2.3.5 on a unix shared hosting account running php v5.3.27.  In my Symfony project I am attempting to use an EventListener to dynamically modify a form because I have some options that can't be determined until after the client is chosen.  I have been following the example in the Symfony cookbook at http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html to build the form.  I have the following code in my form class:

```
<?php
// src/Save/ReportBundle/Form/Type/ReportSettingsType.php
namespace Save\ReportBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;

class ReportSettingsType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('client', 'entity', array(
                'class'=>'Save\ClientBundle\Entity\Client',
                'property'=>'name',
                'label'=>'Client: ',
                'empty_value' => '-- Select Client --'
            ))
            ->add('newReport', 'choice', array(
                'choices' => array(
                    1 => 'Yes',
                    0 => 'No'
                ),
                'label' => 'Run New Report: ',
                'mapped' => false,
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => false
            ))
            ->add('reportType', 'choice', array(
                'choices' => array(
                    'aggregate' => 'Aggregate',
                    'filtered' => 'Filtered'
                ),
                'label' => 'Report Type: ',
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => false
            ))
            ->add('reportSections', 'choice', array(
                'choices' => array(
                    'welcomeLetter' => 'Welcome Letter Page',
                    'reportDetails' => 'Report Details Page',
                    'qualitativeAnalysis' => 'Qualitative Analysis',
                    'statusSummary' => 'Status Summary Graphs',
                    'existingConditions' => 'Existing Conditions Graphs',
                    'priorityActions' => 'Priority Action Plans',
                    'employeeEngagement' => 'Employee Engagement Benchmarks',
                    'futureDiscussions' => 'Future Discussions'
                ),
                'label' => 'Report Sections: ',
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true
            ))
            ->add('processReport', 'submit', array(
                'label' => 'Process Report'
            ));                

        $formModifier = function(FormInterface $form, \Save\ReportBundle\Entity\Report $report){
            $filters = $data->getClient()->getClientAreas();
            $orders = $data->getClient()->getOrders();

            $form->add('order', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'Save\OrderBundle\Entity\Orders',
                'property' => 'selectLabel',
                'choices' => $orders
             ))
             ->add('reportFilter', 'entity', array(
                 'class' => 'Save\ClientBundle\Entity\ClientArea',
                 'property' => 'name',
                 'choices' => $filters
             ));
        };

        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function(FormEvent $event){
                $form = $event->getForm();

                $data = $event->getData();

                $formModifier($event->getForm(), $data);
            });

        $builder->get('client')->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
            function(FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier){
                $report = $event->getForm()->getData();

                $filters = $report->getClient()->getClientAreas();
                $orders = $report->getClient()->getOrders();

                $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $report);
            });         

    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Save\ReportBundle\Entity\Report'
        ));
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'form';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'reportsettingstype';
    } 
}
?>
```

The problem lies with this line `$formModifier($event->getForm(), $data);`
When it calls this line I get the following message

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Function name must be a string in [FILE DIRECTORY]/ReportSettingsType.php line 55
```

I have looked at the PHP documentation on anonymous functions here http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php which utilize the PHP Closure class.  According to everything I've been able to find so far, this should work the way it is written but I am at my wits end trying to figure this one out.

Any constructive help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's missing the `use` keyword for the closure, to close in the variable $formModifier. Since currently there isn't any variable called `$formModifier` to be found inside the anonymous function, PHP complains.

```
$builder->addEventListener(
    FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
    function(FormEvent $event){    // use ($formModifier)
        $form = $event->getForm();

        $data = $event->getData();

        $formModifier($event->getForm(), $data);
});
```